# adding binary numbers without converting to decimal or using built in functions

Tags: python

I'm adding two binary numbers inputted as strings and outputting their sum as a string in binary using this [method](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Binary-Numbers).

Any thoughts on getting my code to work?

```
def add(a,b):
    a = list(a)
    b = list(b)
    equalize(a,b)
    sum_check(a,b,ctr)
    out = " ".join(str(x) for x in sum_check(a,b,ctr))
    out.replace(" ","")
    print(out)

def equalize(a,b):
    if len(a) > len(b):
        for i in range(0, len(a)-len(b)):
            b.insert(0,'0')
    elif len(a) < len(b):
        for i in range(0, len(b)-len(a)):
            a.insert(0,'0')

def sum_check(a,b):

    out = []
    ctr = 0

    def sum(a, b):

        if ctr > 0:
            if a[-1] + b[-1] == 2:
                out.append('1')
            elif a[-1] + b[-1] == 0:
                out.append('1')
                ctr -= 1
            else:  # a[-1] + b[-1] = 1
                out.append('0')
                ctr -= 1
        else:  # ctr = 0
            if a[-1] + b[-1] == 2:
                out.append('1')
                ctr += 1
            elif a[-1] + b[-1] == 0:
                out.append('0')
            else:  # a[-1] + b[-1] = 1
                out.append('1')

    for i in range(len(a)):
        if i == 0:
            sum(a,b)
        else:
            new_a = a[:-1]
            new_b = b[:-1]
            sum(new_a, new_b)

    return out
```

Comment: could someone help me edit my code block? I can't get it to work.

Comment: Lots of potential problems here. But tell us what is your problem: expected vs vad result, or crash then provide error & traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is not really simple (I would rewrite it completely; I would also at least give functions and variables more explicit names in order to understand the algorithm again quicker later, like `ctr` should anyhow explicitely relate to carrying etc.).

Nevertheless, here it is, corrected and working. I have inserted some comments at places where I changed things (either errors in the algorithm, or python programming errors).

I have put `def sum(...)` outside `sum_check`, it's clearer this way.

Though you should know that `sum` is a [python builtin](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#sum), so you should find another name, to avoid losing the builtin in your namespace (but I guess your algorithm is only for training purpose, since you could replace all this by an operation on binary numbers directly:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = int('10110', 2)
>>> b = int('1011100', 2)
>>> bin(a + b)
'0b1110010'
>>>
```

).

Also, I have left some debugging `print` statements, to help to see what happens. Plus an example to check all cases were gone through.

Last note: it first crashed because you used `ctr` before you had defined it. This was the first thing to correct.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def equalize(a, b):
    if len(a) > len(b):
        for i in range(0, len(a) - len(b)):
            b.insert(0, 0)
    elif len(a) < len(b):
        for i in range(0, len(b) - len(a)):
            a.insert(0, 0)
    return a, b


def sum(a, b, ctr):
    out = ''
    print('\n'.join(['-------', 'Working on:',  str(a), str(b)]))

    if ctr > 0:
        if a[-1] + b[-1] == 2:
            out = '1'
            print('Case 1')
        elif a[-1] + b[-1] == 0:
            out = '1'
            ctr -= 1
            print('Case 2')
        else:  # a[-1] + b[-1] = 1
            out = '0'
            print('Case 3')
            # ctr -= 1 (wrong)
    else:  # ctr = 0
        if a[-1] + b[-1] == 2:
            out = '0'  # '1' was wrong
            ctr += 1
            print('Case 4')
        elif a[-1] + b[-1] == 0:
            out = '0'
            print('Case 5')
        else:  # a[-1] + b[-1] = 1
            out = '1'
            print('Case 6')
    print('Sum will return: ' + str(out)
          + ' and carry: ' + str(ctr) + '\n-------')
    return out, ctr


def sum_check(a, b):
    ctr = 0
    out = []
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        if i != 0:
            # You were always giving the same a and b to feed sum().
            # In order to change them, as it's not advised to iterate over a
            # changing list (maybe not even possible), I stored the desired
            # length in a number n. Then, I assign new values to a and b.
            a = a[:-1]
            b = b[:-1]
        new_out, ctr = sum(a, b, ctr)
        out.append(new_out)
        print('Current out: ' + str(out) + ' and carry: ' + str(ctr))
    return out


def add(a, b):
    a = [int(x) for x in a]
    b = [int(x) for x in b]

    # You need to return the new contents of a and b, otherwise you'll keep
    # them as they were before the call to equalize()
    a, b = equalize(a, b)

    print('\n'.join(['Equalized: ', str(a), str(b)]))
    # On next line, [::-1] reverses the result (your algorithm returns a
    # result to be read from right to left)
    print('Result: ' + ''.join(sum_check(a, b)[::-1]))


add('10110', '1011100')
```

Output:

```
Equalized: 
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
-------
Working on:
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
Case 5
Sum will return: 0 and carry: 0
-------
Current out: ['0'] and carry: 0
-------
Working on:
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
Case 6
Sum will return: 1 and carry: 0
-------
Current out: ['0', '1'] and carry: 0
-------
Working on:
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
Case 4
Sum will return: 0 and carry: 1
-------
Current out: ['0', '1', '0'] and carry: 1
-------
Working on:
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
Case 3
Sum will return: 0 and carry: 1
-------
Current out: ['0', '1', '0', '0'] and carry: 1
-------
Working on:
[0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
Case 1
Sum will return: 1 and carry: 1
-------
Current out: ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1'] and carry: 1
-------
Working on:
[0, 0]
[1, 0]
Case 2
Sum will return: 1 and carry: 0
-------
Current out: ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1'] and carry: 0
-------
Working on:
[0]
[1]
Case 6
Sum will return: 1 and carry: 0
-------
Current out: ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'] and carry: 0
Result: 1110010
```

Comment: Great perfect, I think my main problem was that I had used ctr before defining it..

Comment: And yes this is just for practice, I know there is built in binary addition.